# Reference problem with external UI library in React Hook Form

Tags: react-select, react-hook-form

I'm using the ReactSelect component, however, I created a component called Select and ReactSelect is in there:

```
interface IProps extends ISelectProps {
    tabIndex: string;
    required: boolean;
    isClearable: boolean;
    isDisabled: boolean;
    placeholder: string;
    options: {
        label: string;
        value: string;
    }[];
}

const Select = ({ ...props }: IProps) => <ReactSelect {...props} />;

export default Select
```

;

The error is as follows:

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `Controller`.
    at Select
```

Here's the code:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate autoComplete='off'>
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', gap: '0.5rem' }}>
                    {API.map(({ id, order, htmlControl }) => (
                        <Controller
                            key={id}
                            name={id}
                            control={control}
                            render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (
                                <>
                                    {htmlControl.type === 'PARAMETER_TYPE_SELECT' && (
                                        <Select
                                            {...field}
                                            isClearable={true}
                                            error={!!error}
                                            tabIndex={order.toString()}
                                            required={htmlControl.isRequired}
                                            isDisabled={htmlControl.isDisabled}
                                            placeholder={htmlControl.placeholder}
                                            options={htmlControl.options}
                                        />
                                    )}

                                    {htmlControl.type !== 'PARAMETER_TYPE_SELECT' && (
                                        <input
                                            required={htmlControl.isRequired}
                                            disabled={htmlControl.isDisabled}
                                            placeholder={htmlControl.placeholder}
                                        />
                                    )}
                                </>
                            )}
                        />
                    ))}
                </div>

                <input type='submit' />
            </form>
```

I'm following exactly like the official documentation and I can't understand why it can't get the reference.

Answer (score 0):

As you read the warning, it says you are attempting to assign `ref` attribute to a functional component which is not correct, you should not use the `ref` attribute on function components because they don’t have instances. To solve your problem you can define your `Select` component by using [React.forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) like this:

```
const Select = React.forwardRef(({ ...props }, ref) => (
  <ReactSelect {...props} ref={ref} />
));
```